# Xorg Can't open display error and run startx on local with another user on boot

Tags: permissions, x11, xorg, display

I have some trouble setting up a HTPC with Debian 10 (k5.4) and as i'm not a linux expert i wonder if can anybody help me with some questions.

To understand the context I've build a tiny passive cooled HTPC with AMD APU with vega Graphics (amdgpu driver) and i want to install kodi/steam client and some dockers, as the only GUI apps will be kodi and steam client (both run in full screen mode) i have installed the console only Debian 10 and Xorg (no windows manager needed as stated above they both run fullscreen). As i want kodi to autostart at boot i've created another non login user to run kodi as i don't want to run kodi on root.

- `startx kodi` is working without any issues from root user.
- `xclock` is giving

  ```
  Can't open display
  ```

  error and if I

  ```
  echo $DISPLAY
  ```

  nothing is returned (also with root user).
- i've tried to

  ```
  export DISPLAY=:0
  ```

  then run `xclock`, no luck, same error (root user)
- if i run

  ```
  Xorg -configure
  ```

  the conf file is created under `/root` not in `/etc/X11` , also `Xauthority` is in `/root`.
- running `startx kodi` from the non login user after su to it is not possible due to permissions so i've seen that using

  ```
  xhost +kodiuser
  ```

  will grant permissions to that user executed with the root, it dosen't work as xhost is returning the same error

  ```
  Can't open display
  ```
- `w -oush` is returning

  ```
  root     tty1     -                 1:22   -bash
  root     pts/0    192.168.1.210           w -oush
  ```

**Note** that I don't need X11 forwarding as i want the display to be local, is a HTPC machine. On the web all the comments are with `ssh` to the box and advise opening X11 forwarding

I think i'm missing something and maybe my problems are with how is configured Xorg or how is not configured at all, so my question is:

- how to get rid of the "Can't open display" errors and correctly configure Xorg
- how can i give permission to the `kodi` user to run `startx kodi` and select the correct display on local machine (user permissions and Xorg permissions)
- how can i exec this command at boot (start gui on boot without login) as it's not working as it is.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to run `startx` from a `tty` where root isn't logged in, eg `tty2`?

Comment: If i startx from ssh console with root it works even if on local there is nobody logged in or a user without permission (i startx from ssh but i get the app displayed on the local machine), from the kodi-user i get xauthority fail, when i try to add user with xhost i get the same error "Can't open display"

Comment: Is your user in the `video` group?

Comment: No it is not ... should i move it in the video grup??